# C code displaying random datasets

Tags: c++, c

I have much more experience with PAWN scripting language, but I'm digging into K&R book (I think it is it), and trying some stuff on my own.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ITEMS_COUNT 16

unsigned int randr(unsigned int min, unsigned int max);
inline short randomType();
inline char* randomCompanyName();
inline char* randomPersonName();
inline char* randomPersonSurname();
void populateItems();
void dumpItems();

typedef unsigned short int DBID;

typedef struct {
    char name[64];
    char surname[64];
} Person;

typedef struct {
    char name[128];
} Company;

typedef struct {
    unsigned short int type;
    DBID dbID;
    union {
        Person PersonItem;
        Company CompanyItem;
    } chosenItem;
} Item;

enum E_TYPE {
    TYPE_PERSON,
    TYPE_COMPANY
};

Item
    itemList[ITEMS_COUNT];

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /* Init stuff */
    srand(time(NULL));

    populateItems();
    dumpItems();
    return 0;
}

void populateItems() {
    Item
        singleItem;
    size_t
        i = 0;

    for(; i != ITEMS_COUNT; ++i) {
        singleItem.dbID =   i + 1;
        singleItem.type = randomType();

        if(TYPE_PERSON == singleItem.type) {
            strncpy(singleItem.chosenItem.PersonItem.name, randomPersonName(), sizeof(singleItem.chosenItem.PersonItem.name));
            strncpy(singleItem.chosenItem.PersonItem.surname, randomPersonSurname(), sizeof(singleItem.chosenItem.PersonItem.surname));
        } else {
            strncpy(singleItem.chosenItem.CompanyItem.name, randomCompanyName(), sizeof(singleItem.chosenItem.CompanyItem.name));
        }
        memcpy(&itemList[i], &singleItem, sizeof(singleItem));
    }
}

void dumpItems() {
    Item
        *currentItem;
    size_t
        i = 0;
    char
        str[256];

    for(; i != ITEMS_COUNT; ++i) {
        currentItem = &itemList[i];

        //Not safe sprintf!
        sprintf(str, "Row %d: { dbID: %d,", i + 1, currentItem->dbID);

        if(TYPE_PERSON == currentItem->type) {
            sprintf(str, "%s name: %s, surname: %s }", str, currentItem->chosenItem.PersonItem.name, currentItem->chosenItem.PersonItem.surname);
        } else {
            sprintf(str, "%s company name: %s }", str, currentItem->chosenItem.CompanyItem.name);
        }

        printf("%s\n", str);
    }
}

inline short randomType() {
    return randr(0, 1);
}

inline char* randomCompanyName() {
    static char* 
        nameList[32] = {
        "Microsoft",
        "Valve",
        "Vamonos pest",
        "Hello folks!",
        "Just a program inc"
    };
    return nameList[randr(0, 4)];
}

inline char* randomPersonName() {
    static char* 
        nameList[32] = {
        "John",
        "Mike",
        "Emily",
        "Jessica",
        "Steven"
    };
    return nameList[randr(0, 4)];
}

inline char* randomPersonSurname() {
    static char* 
        nameList[32]  = {
        "Ross",
        "Litt",
        "Hellyeah"
    };
    return nameList[randr(0, 2)];
}

unsigned int randr(unsigned int min, unsigned int max)
{
    double 
        scaled = (double) rand() / RAND_MAX;

    return (max - min + 1) * scaled + min;
}
```

I'd like you to tell me if I've made any major mistakes, and how's my coding style. Additionally I have a question about unions. I thought that it simply pointed to regions, and that you didn't have to care later which one you are using, like:

```
//instead of 
singleItem.chosenItem.PersonItem.name
//use
singleItem.chosenItem.name
```

which would point at either PersonItem.name, or CompanyItem.name. How to achieve somthing similar?

Comment: K&R is about _the C language_, `inline` is C++'s alternative/answer/attempt at solving macro issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My little bit of input:

1. `inline` is a C++ keyword, and it's only a hint to the compiler. The only reason to explicitly use `inline` is when you define function's body inside a header file, which is included in more than one source file.
2. [Avoid basic data types like `int`, use types from `stdint.h` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834747/reasons-to-use-or-not-stdint)
3. [Use comments to explain why are you doing something, and what are function arguments for](http://improvingsoftware.com/2011/06/27/5-best-practices-for-commenting-your-code/)
4. No reason to break a line after declaring a type.
5. No reason to give `nameList[32]` a size - the compiler will guess it on its own. Just do it as

   ```
   static char* nameList[]  = {
       "Ross",
       "Litt",
       "Hellyeah"
   };
   ```
6. Use `sizeof(nameList) - 1` instead of a magic number to indicate last array index - there will be less changes if you ever add more names.

Regarding your union questions:

`union` is kinda like a `struct`; the only difference is how it's handled in memory.
Since your `union` has two fields (`PersonItem` and `CompanyItem`), you must say which one is to be used. Every object created with your `struct` will contain both fields. What you're trying to do is called polymorphism, and you have it with classes in C++. Original C does not have such option.

Comment: Also: read this, it should help you with code quality, even though it's not for C :) http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/top-15-best-practices-for-writing-super-readable-code/

Comment: You might cringe a little, but I'm a professional webdeveloper (+ php scripter) (as in earn money for living with, not skill level yet) - don't worry though, I stick to php-psr.

I didn't know that inline is C++ only, and I had no clue about badness of builtin datatypes - thanks for that.

Comment: I know that unions are structs with each element pointing to index 0 (I guess). And those 32 were to tell future coders that you can't go over 31 + NUL limit.

I wanted to master C (at least syntax) before moving on to C++, but I think I know what you're talking about (virtual classes and stuff)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :) I know what you mean, I'm a professional C++ developer as in earn money for a living, not skill level yet :)

Comment: Ok :) In that case, since you know what you're doing I have nothing to add :) Good luck :)

Comment: Regarding the `inline`, I believe everything included in the header becomes inline by default (I'm not sure if you were implying that).

Comment: No. Directive "#include" makes everything from the header pasted into source file, but it doesn't mean inlining. If you have `void someFunction() {}` in a header, which is not inline, and you include that header in more than one source file you'll get linking error "multiple definitions". It's likely that a good compiler will inline such function by itself, and solve the problem, but there is no guarantee of that.

Comment: Oh! I've found out about anonymous unions (part of C11), so instead currentItem->chosenItem.PersonItem.name I can use currentItem->PersonItem.name. Good to know that

Comment: @DarthHunterix your point 1 is untrue, `inline` is in c99. Your point 2 is not appropriate here.  There is no reason not to use int/char etc in this code.  Your point 6 is wrong - `sizeof(nameList)` is the size in bytes of `nameList`, not the number of `char*` entries in the array.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has a number of issues.

It is often better to layout the code in reverse order.  This avoids the need
for local prototypes.  For example, `main` goes last in the file and the
functions it calls are above it.  `inline` functions must be defined before
they are used - another reason for doing things backwards.  Note that the
compiler can decide for itself what should be inline and what not, so using
'inline' is normally unnecessary.

You have defined `emum E_TYPE` but not used it in `struct Item`, where it is
needed.  Instead you use `unsigned short int type`.  Note that all-caps names
are usually constants, so `E_TYPE` would be better as `type`.  Function
`randomType` should return an `enum type`, not a `short` and should use the
values defined for the enum.  The union in your `Item` struct need not have a
name and its field names are verbose.   Here is how I would simplify it:

```
typedef struct {
    enum type type;
    DBID id;
    union {
        Person person;
        Company company;
    };
} Item;
```

General point: don't put the type and variable on separate lines.  Nobody does that.

Functions with no parameters should be defined with a `void` in the parameter
list.  The compiler should warn you about that (compile with warnings turned
on - use at least the option -W with gcc).

In your `randomCompanyName` etc functions, the name list should be `const`.
When selecting the random name using

```
return nameList[randr(0, 4)];
```

instead of an explicit 4, you should derive the value from the array:

```
const char* nameList[] = {
    "Microsoft",
    "Valve",
    "Vamonos pest",
    "Hello folks!",
    "Just a program inc"
};
const int listSize = sizeof nameList / sizeof nameList[0];
return nameList[randr(0, listSize - 1)];
```

You can do this only if you omit the size of the array.

Your `randr` is almost correct, but should divide by `RANDMAX + 1`

```
double scaled = rand() / (1.0 + RAND_MAX);
```

Your `populateItems` function is not very readable.  For a start, it is
generally best not to exceed about 80 characters per line.  It is also odd to
create an `Item` and then copy that into the global array.  Why not create it
directly in the correct array entry?  Also, define the loop variable in the
loop, not above it.

Your use of `strncpy` in the loop is a problem.  `strncpy` does not do what
you might expect when there is not enough space.  It does not terminate the
truncated string!  To do it properly you must terminate each string
explicitly.  This is messy.  The alternative copy function `strlcpy` that gets
it right but is not universally available (and hence is non-portable).
An alternative, perhaps nicer , is to get your `randomCompanyName` etc
functions,  to fill the string buffer themselves:

```
static char* randomCompanyName(char *buf, size_t size)
{
    static char* nameList[] = { ...
    };
    const int listSize = sizeof nameList / sizeof nameList[0];
    const char *name = nameList[randr(0, listSize - 1)];
    strncpy(buf, name, size);
    buf[size - 1] = '\0';
    return buf;
}
```

Putting these together, `populateItems` then becomes rather easier to read:

```
static void populateItems(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ITEMS_COUNT; ++i) { // note < not !=
        Item *it = &itemList[i];
        it->id = i + 1;
        it->type = randomType();

        if (it->type = TYPE_PERSON) {
            randomPersonName(it->person.name, sizeof it->person.name);
            randomPersonSurname(it->person.surname, sizeof it->person.surname);
        } else {
            randomCompanyName(it->company.name, sizeof it->company.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Your `dumpItems` uses `sprintf` to create a string but overwrites the first
part ("Row %ld: { dbID: %d,") with the second part ("%s name: %s, surname: %s
}") as it does not index into `str`.  `sprintf` like `strcpy` etc is a common
source of buffer overruns.  You could use `snprintf` instead, but really why
bother?  It would be much easier just to print the two parts of the string
directly to `stdout`.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I have question though: is using static for every function some kind of convention? (even if the program is single file) Didn't know that bit about strncpy, I was a little confused when I saw 20 diffrent strcpy variations. 

Oh, and I don't know why I used the new instance -> memcpy thingy, I think I didn't know then about the -> operator and thought I'd have to use (*it).stuff all the time. 

http://pastebin.com/Tp30jhTE - much more readable now.

Comment: Functions should be `static` if they will never be used outside the file that defines them. For a single-file program this doesn't matter, but adding the `static` to each function keeps my compiler silent (gcc warning `-Wmissing-prototypes`). I just forgot to remove them.